# having trouble with the implementation of a cash register function

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning Javascript, and I completed the freeCodeCamp cash register JS project https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures-projects/cash-register . I am now trying to create a cash register website to implement and demonstrate this. The initial function was correct, but now I am adding a user price input and payment input, and the function should return when the button is clicked. I have not been able to get it to work. here is the link to my github repo: https://github.com/aaronnwg/Cash-Register . Any guidance as to what is missing, or what needs to be changed would be greatly appreciated.

After building the HTML page, I tried:

```
const price = document.getElementById('price');
const cash = document.getElementById('payment');
//cid is already declared
const cashRegisterFunction = () => {
  
  document.getElementById('return').innerHTML = checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid)
}
button.onClick = cashRegisterFunction();
```

My expectation is that the user will input 'price' and 'payment', and when the button is clicked, checkCashRegister function should return in the 'return'.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the parentheses, so that you pass a function reference and not a function call:

```js
button.onclick = cashRegisterFunction
```

Comment: this unfortunately didn't solve the issue.  But it does seem like the button is possibly the source of the problem, but I am unsure, I am a beginner.

Comment: I just updated the code. Can you try with lowercase method name?

Comment: Im sorry for my ignorance, but i don't understand what you mean by 'lowercase method name'. do you mean toLowerCase() method? that confuses me because the input and output, are numbers and an array not strings. could you please elaborate?

Comment: The onClick should be onclick. The C should be lowercase c.